# Printing results from ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean

My assignment question is:

Store these values for the fifteen candidates in an extended AddressBook class.

- In general, Google will not consider a candidate with average marks of less than 85%.
- Google will consider a candidate with average marks of less than 85% only if the candidate at least has 0.5 regulatory abilities and at least ‘average’ ability to communicate.
- Google will only consider a candidate with poor communication ability if the candidate has a ‘brilliant’ innovation capability.

Write a program that will help Google to programmatically determine eligibility of the fifteen candidates for these positions, and print the output on the console.

The main class is only supposed to be used for entering data and printing.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import Question1.AddressBook;
import Question4.BanffMarathonRunner;

public class Candidate extends AddressBook { //extension of Question 1

    private double grade;
    private String communication;
    private boolean innovation;
    private double regulation;
    
    public Candidate (String fn, String ln, double grade, String comm, boolean innov, double reg) {
        super(fn, " ", ln); //constructor
        this.grade = grade; //stores grade
        this.communication = comm; //stores communication score
        this.innovation = innov; //stores innovation score
        this.regulation = reg; //stores ability to regulate ones own skill score
    }
    
    /* Return grade
     * return double*/
    public double getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
    
    /*Set time to the value passed through the parameter.
    * parameter grade - grade
    * return void*/
    public void setGrade(double grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    
    /* Return communication
     * return string*/
    public String getCommunication() {
        return communication;
    }
    
    /*Set time to the value passed through the parameter.
    * parameter communication - commm
    * return void*/
    public void setCommunication(String comm) {
        this.communication = comm;
    }
    
    /* Return innovation
     * return double*/
    public boolean getInnovation() {
        return innovation;
    }
    
    /*Set time to the value passed through the parameter.
    * parameter innovation - innov
    * return void*/
    public void setInnovation(boolean innov) {
        this.innovation = innov;
    }
    
    /* Return regulation
     * return double*/
    public double getRegulation() {
        return regulation;
    }
    
    /*Set time to the value passed through the parameter.
    * parameter regulation - reg
    * return void*/
    public void setRegulation(double reg) {
        this.regulation = reg;
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<Candidate> getEligibleCandidate (Candidate[] cands) {
        ArrayList<Candidate> list = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
        System.out.println("Google will consider candidates with an average mark above 85%, \n" 
                + "and candidates who have an average below 85% if their regulation score is at or above 0.5 \n"
                + "and a communication score of ‘average’ or 'brilliant'.\n"
                + "The eligible candidates are; \n");
        
        for (Candidate candidateA : cands) {
            
            if (candidateA.getGrade() > 85.00) {
                System.out.println(candidateA.getFirstName() + " " + candidateA.getLastName() 
                + "\nGrade - " + candidateA.getGrade() + "\n");   
            }
            if ((candidateA.getGrade() < 85.00) && (candidateA.getRegulation() >= 0.5) 
                    && (candidateA.getCommunication() != "poor")) {
                
                System.out.println(candidateA.getFirstName() + " " + candidateA.getLastName() 
                        + "\nGrade - " + candidateA.getGrade() 
                        + "\nRegulation - " + candidateA.getRegulation() 
                        + "\nCommunication - " + candidateA.getCommunication() + "\n"); 
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    public boolean isInnovative (Candidate[] cands)  {
        
        for (Candidate candidateA : cands) {
            boolean brilliant = true;
            if (candidateA.getGrade() > 85.00) 
                return false;
            if (candidateA.getRegulation() < 0.5) 
                return false;
            if (candidateA.getCommunication() != "poor") 
                return false;
            if (candidateA.getInnovation() != brilliant) 
                return false;
            if (candidateA.getGrade() < 85.00 && candidateA.getRegulation() >= 0.5 
                    && candidateA.getCommunication() == "poor" && candidateA.getInnovation() == brilliant) {
                System.out.println("Google will also consider a candidate with poor communication ability\n" 
                    + "if the candidate has a ‘brilliant’ innovation capability. The eligible candidates are; \n"
                    + candidateA.getFirstName() + " " + candidateA.getLastName() + "\n" 
                    + "Communication: \n" + candidateA.getCommunication() + "Innovation: " 
                    + candidateA.getInnovation());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestCandidate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        boolean brilliant = true;
        boolean average = false;
        
        Candidate [] cands = new Candidate[15]; //Array of candidates
           
        cands[0] = new  Candidate ("Elena", "Brandon", 82.30, "poor", brilliant, 0.5);
        cands[1] = new  Candidate ("Thomas", "Molson", 85.10, "poor", average, 1.0);
        cands[2] = new  Candidate ("Hamilton", "Winn", 77.77, "average", average, 0.8);
        cands[3] = new  Candidate ("Suzie", "Sarandin", 69.93, "average", average, 0.0);
        cands[4] = new  Candidate ("Philip", "Winne", 93.03, "average", brilliant, 1.0);
        cands[5] = new  Candidate ("Alex", "Trebok", 88.61, "poor", brilliant, 0.7);
        cands[6] = new  Candidate ("Emma", "Pivoto", 55.99, "excellent", average, 0.8);
        cands[7] = new  Candidate ("John", "Lenthen", 87.49, "excellent", brilliant, 0.9);
        cands[8] = new  Candidate ("James", "Lean", 88.00, "excellent", average, 0.5);
        cands[9] = new  Candidate ("Jane", "Ostin", 91.20, "average", brilliant, 0.6);
        cands[10] = new Candidate ("Emily", "Car", 66.79, "excellent", average, 0.3);
        cands[11] = new Candidate ("Daniel", "Hamshire", 76.65, "average", brilliant, 0.2);
        cands[12] = new Candidate ("Neda", "Bazdar", 55.89, "excellent", brilliant, 0.5);
        cands[13] = new Candidate ("Aaron", "Smith", 90.01, "excellent", average, 0.3);
        cands[14] = new Candidate ("Kate", "Hen", 87.90, "poor", average, 0.8);
    
        ArrayList<Candidate> list = Candidate.getEligibleCandidate(cands);         
    }
}
```

I cannot get the boolean statement to print out the results.  This is my last question in this assignment I my brain is jello.  Please help!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have some unnecessary code like setters and getters that clutters up the question

Comment: What "boolean statement" does not "print out the results"?

Comment: What you expect your code to do and why? What happens instead? Are you perhaps confusing `printi`ng value with `return`ing value?

Comment: The getter and setters are required as a part of the question.  The public boolean isInnovative (Candidate[] cands)  is not returning a value.